# How to approximate the flux when using finite volumes?

Tags: numerics, finite-volume, discretization, navier-stokes, approximation

How to approximate flux $F(u)\cdot n$ where $n$ denotes the unit normal outward when using finite volumes?

$$\int_{\sigma} F(u) \cdot \boldsymbol{n}_{K, \sigma} \mathrm{d} \gamma(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

The integral may be approximated with

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial \Omega} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}} \cdot \vec{n} ~ds \approx \sum_k L_k \mathbf{T}^{-1}\vec{F}\left(\mathbf{T}~ \vec{u}\right)
\end{align},
$$

where $L_k$ is the length of each side and $\mathbf{T}$ is a rotation matrix.

---

**tl;dr**

The answer depends on your equation system. Using the conservation laws in two dimensions, e.g. Euler equations **(rotation invariant)**

$$
\vec{u}_t + \vec{F}\left(\vec{u}\right)_x + \vec{G}\left(\vec{u}\right)_y = \vec{0},
$$

with

$$
\begin{align}
\vec{u}=
\left( \begin{array}{r}
u_1  \\
u_2  \\
u_3  \\
u_4
\end{array}\right)
,\quad
\vec{F}\left(\vec{u}\right)=
\left( \begin{array}{r}
F_1\left(\vec{u}\right)  \\
F_2\left(\vec{u}\right)  \\
F_3\left(\vec{u}\right)  \\
F_4\left(\vec{u}\right)
\end{array}\right)
,\quad
\vec{G}\left(\vec{u}\right)=
\left( \begin{array}{r}
G_1\left(\vec{u}\right)  \\
G_2\left(\vec{u}\right)  \\
G_3\left(\vec{u}\right)  \\
G_4\left(\vec{u}\right)
\end{array}\right),
\end{align}
$$

you can write

$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}\cdot \vec{n}\equiv\left[\vec{G}\left(\vec{u}\right),\vec{F}\left(\vec{u}\right)\right]\cdot \vec{n} =  n_1 \vec{F}\left(\vec{u}\right)+ n_2 \vec{G}\left(\vec{u}\right) = \mathbf{T}^{-1}\vec{F}\left(\mathbf{T}~ \vec{u}\right)
\end{align},
$$

where

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{T}=&
\left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & n_1 & n_2 & 0 \\
0 & -n_2 & n_1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & n & 1 \\
\end{array}\right),  \quad 
\mathbf{T}^{-1}=
\left( \begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & n_1 & -n_2 & 0 \\
0 & n_2 & n_1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right),\\[1em] \vec{n}&\equiv \left( n_1, n_2 \right) = \left(\cos\left(\phi\right), \sin\left(\phi\right)\right),
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{T} ~ \vec{u}=
\left( \begin{array}{c}
u_1  \\
n_1 u_1  + n_2 u_2   \\
-n_2 u_1  + n_1 u_2  \\
u_4
\end{array}\right)
,\quad
\mathbf{T}^{-1} ~ \vec{F}=
\left( \begin{array}{c}
F_1  \\
n_1 F_1\left(\vec{u}\right)  - n_2 F_2\left(\vec{u}\right)   \\
n_2 F_1\left(\vec{u}\right) + n_1 F_2\left(\vec{u}\right)  \\
F_4
\end{array}\right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Si on prends $F=(\frac{-u^2}{2}-u,\frac{-u^2}{2}-u)$ avec $u$ est un scalaire, comment l'approximer

Comment: For a scalar value pick the first line of the equation system above.

Comment: May I please contact you for more information, and how can I do it?

Comment: in my case it's not a conservation law so it won't work, my question is how can we approximate the final term 
\begin{align}
\int_{k} div(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}(u)) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\partial K} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}(u) \cdot \vec{n} ~ds \end{align},
if we are working with triangular mesh, this integral is equal to
 \begin{align}
\sum_{\sigma \in \epsilon_k} \int_{\sigma} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F(u)}}\cdot \vec{n_{\sigma}} ~ds
\end{align},
So finally how can we approximate this integral

Comment: @ChemsEddine The divergence theorem as stated above is employed in any conservation law. Are you rather interested in approximations for conservative fields using elliptic PDE's? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

Comment: I'm sorry but my question is when we get to that term 
\begin{align} \sum_{\sigma \in \epsilon_k} \int_{\sigma} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F(u)}}\cdot \vec{n_{\sigma}} ~ds \end{align}
\begin{align}  \int_{\sigma} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F(u)}}\cdot \vec{n_{\sigma}} ~ds = |\sigma| \phi(u_K , u_L, \sigma_{K,L})  \end{align}
how to chose function $\phi$
Ps : the initial problem is in the form 
\begin{align} \Delta^2(u)=div(F(u))
\end{align}