# Finite volume method for a general flux

Tags: numerics, finite-volume, approximation

How to approximate flux ()⋅ where  denotes the unit normal outward when using finite volumes?
in my case it's not a conservation law so my question is how can we approximate the final term
\begin{align}
\int_{k} div(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}(u)) \mathrm{d}x = \int_{\partial K} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}(u) \cdot \vec{n} ~ds \end{align},
if we are working with triangular mesh, this integral is equal to
\begin{align}
\sum_{\sigma \in \epsilon_k} \int_{\sigma} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}(u)\cdot \vec{n_{\sigma}} ~ds
\end{align},
So finally how can we approximate this integral (note that $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}(u)$ is on the form $$\boldsymbol{\mathcal{F}}(u)=(-\dfrac{u^2}{2}-u,-\dfrac{u^2}{2}-u)$$
Sorry, for the long question but I think by providing my full methodology, my confusion will be clear to the reader.

Comment: Next time, please consider to edit your old question, instead of creating a new one. https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/43605/how-to-approximate-the-flux-when-using-finite-volumes/43606